# Any good source to teach my self Vedic Sanskrit?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, sanskrit

Keep in mind, I'm talking about the archaic form of Sanskrit which is used in the Vedas, I have a desire to learn Vedic Sanskrit

Comment: What other type of Sanskrit is there ?

Comment: Classical Sanskrit, the one used in Puranas and Ithihasas.

Comment: the only difference between the two is swaras. It's like saying there is a difference between Prose English vs Poetry English.

Comment: The language is quite different, it's not really about Prose vs Poetry, Sanskrit of the Ithihasas and Puranas was standardized around the time of Panini, Vedas are much older and the language is more archaic.

Comment: That is a common misconception that Panini standardized Sanskrit. Panini did not invent Sanskrit grammar. Sanskrit grammar is timeless and eternal. All Panini did was codify Sanskrit's grammar into sutras or formulas. The same can (and was) codified using different formulas before Panini also. Think of it as writing Newton's law of gravity using Latin alphabet vs Greek alphabet. The law (grammar) is eternal. Only the letters (sutras) change. Panini's Sutras are the effect, not the cause of Sanskrit grammar. FYI, I teach Sanskrit at Sanskrita Bharati.

Comment: Why did I ever say that Paini is the one who did it? I said around Panini's time, look I respect your religious beliefs but I'd much rather look at Sanskrit like a language that is a product of this world (just like any other language) rather than some timeless god-given thing. 

Sanskrit also evolved, I am just  trying to learn the archaic form of Sanskrit which was used in the Rig Veda.

Comment: whether by Panini, or around time of Panini, both mean that some 'human' 'standardized' it and everyone decided to follow those rules. But that is not true. Sanskrit never evolved. It is static, god-given and perfect. The underlying premise of your question itself is incorrect. If you learn Panini Sanskrit, you learn Vedic Sanskrit (with a few exceptions since Panini himself says he has not codified everything in Vedas inside his ~4000 sutras, so others are Aarshyam i.e. made by rishis). If you are interested solely in Sanskrit linguistics, you could check with linguistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mar Tones are also a big difference. Unless you meant tones with svaras.